# Is there a cleaner way to map an object to a class (e.g. using a dictionary)?

Tags: c#

```cs
public static class SceneToGame{
    public static GameParentServer Server(int scene, Server server){
        switch (scene){
            case 1:
                return new SnapGameServer(server);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm currently using this to map ints to classes with a common parent. Is there a cleaner way to do this? From what I've read you can't because C# is type safe despite this being type safe.

Comment: Yes, you could use a `Dictionary<int, Func<Server, GameParentServer>>` to do this

Comment: Depending on your compiler / language version, maybe a [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) would be cleaner?

Comment: I do not like mapping an int to an object of a specific type. At least you should use an enum.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do the factory design pattern or something close to it. I'd read up on that.

Comment: This is ambiguous, in the title you want to map `object to class`, but in the question what you did is map `int to object`

Comment: @B.O.B. it is a common misconception that the a method generating objects is the "Factory Method pattern". The actual pattern has to do with inheritance, quote _"Define an interface for creating an object, but let subclasses decide which class to instantiate. The Factory method lets a class defer instantiation it uses to subclasses."_.

Comment: @JHBonarius Ah thanks for the info. I personally don't use the factory method pattern. Their code sample just reminded me of what little examples I've seen online of it. Course those examples were probably flawed too.

Answer (score 2):

Applying the changes suggested by @clemens and @richard-deeming in comments on the original post, here is a possible implementation; using an `enum` rather than `int` for `scene`, and a `switch expression` (available from C# 8 [[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression)]) rather than a `switch statement`.

```
public enum SceneType
{
    Undefined, //Undefined = 0,
    Snap,      //Snap = 1,
    Ultra,     //Ultra = 2,
    Ninja      //Ninja = 3
}
```

As pointed out by @oliver in the comments to this answer, adding a `default` value (in this example, `Undefined`) in your enum will ensure that if any `SceneType` variable in your code is not populated, the value of that variable will default to `Undefined` rather than e.g. `Snap`.

Unless you really need to make sure that `SceneType.Snap` has the numerical value of `1` (and so on), your `enum` does not need to define specific numerical values for each enum value.

```
public static GameParentServer Server(SceneType scene, Server server)
{
    return scene switch
    {
        Snap  => new SnapGameServer(server),
        Ultra => new UltraGameServer(server),
        Ninja => new NinjaGameServer(server),
        _ => null
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be my answer too, but I would add an `Undefined` value as first entry to the enum to not fall into the *Snap case* by accident (and it would result in getting the `1` to match `Snap`).

Comment: Well thought! That's why I let the input parameter be `SceneType?`rather than `SceneType`, but your suggestion is better/safer. I will update my answer.

Comment: @Oliver how would you "fall into [first case] by accident"? If that's possible here, I think I'm missing essential C# knowledge, so I'm very curious...

Comment: Depending on your overall structure (e.g. this value is a property in another class) it could happen that you forgot to initialize this variable with a specific value, which would mean, this variable holds its default value (which is zero) and this could lead to *false paths* through your code.  Just to be sure to define a proper default value for your enum. See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/enum

Comment: @Oliver but will that here not take the default `_ => null` path?

Comment: The first defined name within an enum gets the underlying value `0`. If (in this case) your first enum would be *Snap*, then `var type = default(SceneType)` would be *Snap* and the switch statement would **not** take the `null` path. For better understanding, here is a code sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ObIIGd

Answer (score 1):

One potential method might be to use reflection to enable intelligent mapping to the GameParentServer child. The primary benefit of this method is that it will use a few lines of codes, and won't require changes to the mapping for every new value of 'scene'. This fits my definition of clean, although opinions can vary.

Edit:
As @JHBonarius has pointed out, it's worth considering that there is a performance hit when using this approach. Based on the name of your class - GameServerParent - my presumption is that this is a heavy object that will be initialised only once per application execution. In this scenario, the performance hit here is perfectly acceptable. However, for smaller objects that are constantly initialised, this approach might degrade performance too heavily to be useable. We can discuss implementing a cache of this information if your GameServerParent objects are something you intend to initialise constantly.

To implement this approach, we simply add an identifier attribute to the relevant GameParentServer child classes.

```
public class GameServerAttribute: Attribute
{
    public GameServerAttribute(int gameServerId)
    {
        GameServerId = gameServerId;
    }

    private int GameServerId { get; }
}
```

Then, we add to this to the classes that inherit GameParentServer:

```
[GameServer(1)]
public class SnapGameServer : GameParentServer
{
    public SnapGameServer(Server server) : base(server)
    {
    }
}
```

Now, we just need to modify the mapping to actually use the attribute and call the constructor via reflection:

```
public static class SceneToGame{
    public static GameParentServer Server(int scene, Server server)
    {
        Type types = Assembly
            .GetCallingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.GetCustomAttributes()
                                     .Contains(new GameServerAttribute(scene)) 
                                 && t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(GameParentServer)));

        return (GameParentServer) types?
            .InvokeMember("", BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, new object?[] {server});
    }
}
```

This code identifies the assembly that is calling the code, retrieves the types in the assembly, and then checks if they have an instance of our new custom attribute with the passed value. If so, we take the first one, and then invoke the constructor, passing in the server parameter.

You are now free to add new [GameServer(scene)] attributes to any class, and a passed int will automatically map to the relevant class. Please keep in mind that my example does not handle construction exceptions, or classes that have duplicate scene values. I also would recommend using an enum instead of an int for mapping, as it will be easier to read and maintain.

One last note, my example here makes the assumption that the classes that inherit GameParentServer are all in the same assembly, and that this assembly is making the call to this code. If you have separated them out, you'll need to retrieve the types of the different assemblies in order to find the applicable types.

Comment: Reflection?? You might want to mention the performance hit when using reflection... Don't use reflection when you don't have to.

Comment: @JHBonarius I don't think this answer is bad. Performance issue can be solved by initializing dictionary<int, type> with reflection once at application start. It will be flexible and fast solution.

Comment: @Maxim I'm not saying it's bad (and thus didn't downvote), but I think you always need to mention the impact of using reflection. (And If you think it's good, why didn't you upvote?)

Comment: Thanks @JHBonarius, that's a valid concern I should've covered in my answer. I've amended my answer explaining the potential performance hit. For clarity, I suggested reflection here because the name of the class implied it was a heavy object, where the performance hit of initialising via reflection is acceptable.

Comment: @DonTickner people refer to Stack Overflow for related issues, so generalization of answers should always be considered.